# troubleshooting JAXBUnmarshalException: Unexpected end of stream (RESTeasy)

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I would appreciate if someone could help me formulate a strategy for fixing the following error, which occurs in no discernible pattern; most of the time there is no error, and I am successful about 90% of the time:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher]  Failed executing POST /toys/customer25/insert
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: Unexpected end of stream
```

How would I log this error simply to the console?  I'd like to capture the JSON that this method is receiving and figure out what is causing this error.  I would be able to see it in the server logs.

What I am doing is POSTing an array of `Toy` objects to the server, in JSON format.  That is, on the client I transform my `Toy` object into a `Toy` JSON.  The string that I am sending is like this:  `[{"toyName":"buzzlightyear", "toyMaker":"mattel"}]`

My understanding is that when I POST JSON to a jax-rs restful service, a jax-rs implementation (I'm using RESTeasy 1.2) will somehow automagically convert that JSON string into a java `Toy` object.

My code on the Java JAX-RS restful service for handling a POST which inserts a `Toy` object is this:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("toy/{customer}/insert")
public String insertToys(@PathParam("customer") String customer, List<Toy> toys);
```

How do I log/capture what is wrong with the JSON string?  It seems to me that the system is handling the conversion of the JSON to Toy object right when the `insertToys()` method is called.  So it's hard form to figure out how to debug.

Can someone formulate a strategy for me?  What is the likelihood that I am passing in malformed JSON, maybe from some unescaped character?  Vs mapping entities wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Unexpected EOF means: The program was expecting somethin (a closing bracket, a closin tag) and the input ended (got EOF) before that. Check it.

Comment: Hi, how can I log the raw json string that is being submitted and received by my JAX-RS insert method?  Request object?  I don't see how to get the request body.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is incorrect.
The method accepts List, so you must send an array of Toy Objects:

```
[{"toyName":"buzzlightyear", "toyMaker":"mattel"}]
```

(note the braces).

For more objects:

```
[{"toyName":"buzzlightyear", "toyMaker":"mattel"},{"toyName":"rex", "toyMaker":"mattel"}]
```

Comment: Apologies, this was a typo.  I have corrected the JSON.  Some objects are still failing to be inserted with the JAXB unexpected end of stream exception.  I guess the question is, how do I look at what is being unmarshaled to find the error? Or when the jaxb runtime throws this exception, where would I catch it in my code?  In the jax-rs method (public String insertToys()...)?